# Trying to run prompt through pandasai and receiving index error

Tags: python

I'm trying to use pandasai by to pull back answers from a csv file dataframe. I keep getting an error that our index is out of range. Has anyone who has played with pandasai recieved this error before and know why this may be occuring? Sometimes it gives us the answer and other times it tells us our list index if out of range.

'Unfortunately, I was not able to answer your question, because of the following error:\n\nlist index out of range\n'

We were expecting pandasai to find the answer from the df we gave it.